# dual-monitor "infinite desktop" for the cursor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have a dual-screen Windows 7 set-up. The monitors are set side-by side, and I have it configured so that I can move the cursor directly from one screen to the other. i.e. The right edge of Monitor 1 is next to the left edge of Monitor 2.

When I move my cursor to the right edge of Monitor 1, it automatically goes to the left edge of Monitor 2 (and vice versa). However, the left edge of Monitor 1 and the right edge of Monitor 2 are "hard" edges- the cursor stops up against them.

Here is what I'd like: an infinite loop for the cursor to travel between monitors. Cursor past  the right edge of Monitor 1, appear on the left edge of Monitor 2. Continue cursoring past the right edge of Monitor 2, appear once again on the left edge of Monitor 1. Infinite. As long as I keep moving the mouse in one direction, it keeps moving between monitors.

I waste lots of time (subconsciously) figuring out how to get the cursor on the correct screen. Is there a setting or a software app that will let me get the infinite effect?

Comment: A lot of time? Might just want to make the cursor bigger and easier to find. . .

Comment: you can use MouseKeys (ctrlpanel->mouse->accessiblity) to control the mouse with the keyboard

Comment: To find the cursor position just go to control panel > mouse > pointer options > Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key and, if needed, show pointer trails http://www.trishtech.com/img_art_a/win7_mouse_pointer_1.jpg

Comment: I made an AutoIt script that basically does this - it's available here: https://github.com/angel333/infinimouse